# Transcendence of function and change of fields

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, transcendence-theory, transcendental-functions

Suppose the one has a sequence of rational functions $Q_n(z)\in\mathbb Q(z)$. Let $p$ be a prime number. Suppose that that there exists an infinite subset $X$ of $\mathbb Q_p$ such that:

1. the functions $Q_n$ are defined on $X$
2. for all $z\in X$, $\lim_{n\to+\infty}Q_n(z)=0$ in $\mathbb Q_p$
3. the function $F(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}Q_n(z)$ is transcendental on $\mathbb Q(z)$; that is:
   for any polynomials $P_0,\cdots,P_n$ of $\mathbb Q[z]$ not all zero, there exists $z\in X$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^nP_i(z)F^i(z)\ne0$

My question now: considers an another prime $p'$ and $Y$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb Q_{p'}$. Suppose that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, the functions $Q_n$ are definied on $Y$ and for every $z\in Y$, one has $\lim_{n\to+\infty}Q_n(z)=0$ in $\mathbb Q_{p'}$.

Is the function $G(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}Q_n(z)$ (considered as a function defined on $Y\subset\mathbb Q_{p'}$) transcendental on $\mathbb Q[z]$?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: What have you tried, and what's the motivation of this problem?

Comment: edited! thnaks for the notification Torsten

Comment: Thanks for editing. But now, are there not already counterexamples in constant functions? Like, take a sequence of rationals $a_n$ which converges to a rational number in $\mathbb Q_p$ but to a transcendental number in $\mathbb Q_{p'}$. Then let $Q_n$ be the constant function with $Q_n(z) = a_{n+1}-a_n$.